# Including TikZ file: the key '/tikz/cap' requires a value

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-external

I'm trying to include a file with a specific shape (cup) into another TikZ image, in order to use the cup as a "stamp" to draw more complex figure. The file is located in /usr/share/tikzit/shapes/cap.tikz

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\pagestyle{empty}

\pgfdeclarelayer{edgelayer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{nodelayer}
\pgfsetlayers{edgelayer,nodelayer,main}

\tikzstyle{none}=[inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{node1}=[cap,fill=White,draw=Black]

\tikzstyle{simple}=[-,draw=Black,line width=2.000]
\tikzstyle{arrow}=[-,draw=Black,postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{>}}},line width=2.000]
\tikzstyle{tick}=[-,draw=Black,postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\draw (0,-0.1) -- (0,0.1);}},line width=2.000]

\usepackage[graphics,tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\newlength{\imagewidth}
\newlength{\imagescale}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
        \node [style=node1] (0) at (-2.5, 1.5) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The code i want to include is the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \path [use as bounding box] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
                \node [style=none] (0) at (0, 0.75) {};
                \node [style=none] (1) at (-0.5, 0) {};
                \node [style=none] (2) at (0.5, 0) {};
        \end{pgfonlayer}
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
                \draw [in=0, out=90] (2.center) to (0.center);
                \draw [in=270, out=-90, looseness=0.75] (1.center) to (2.center);
                \draw [in=90, out=180] (0.center) to (1.center);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But it seems I miss how to specify the directory of cup. I get this error:

> Package pgfkeys Error: The key '/tikz/cap' requires a value. I am
>   going to ignore this key.

It seems like I have to deal with tikzstyle or pgfkey, but I don't know how to specify an external file.

Comment: You have nore problems in your MWE: (i) cap is defined in `arrows.meta` as part of determination of lines end, there is required to specify angle. If you have something else in mind, you need to select different name and defined its meaning.  (ii) nowhere in the first image is given link to your second image and including an image as option to node style is not posible. (iii) `tikzstyle` is obsolete, better is to use `tikzset`. (iv) for ordinary lines is not need to set option `-`, etc

Comment: Can you provide a sketch, how desired picture  should like.

Comment: What are the nodes for exactly? In the example, they seem unnecessary, but perhaps you intend to use them for some purpose?

Comment: It would be best to avoid `none` as a style name, too, as that already has meaning (`draw=none` etc.). The same for `tick` and `arrow`.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in my comment, TikZ doesn't allow to use pictures as options for node. Your problem, if I understood correct your question, can be solved by use of small pictures titled `pic`. They are described in section "18 Pics: Small Pictures on Paths" in manual for TikZ v3.0 and newest (in recent version 3.0.1a it star on page 251).

- your image you design as small pictures and cal them in any document as `\pic {name of pic};
- designed pictures store in \tikzset{...} and store  it in private style package, for example "my_TikZ_presets", about which LaTeX had to be aware (i.e.: store it somewhere in local tree and update LaTeX file name database;
- in documents, where you like to use thoise pictures, you need to load this style, and in TikZ pictures set options for used `tikzset` (see code below)

Below is MWE, which demonstrate aforementioned.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,positioning,shapes.geometric}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \tikzset{PIC/.style = {%this you can store for example as 
                           % my_TikZ-presets.style somewhere, 
                           % where (La)TeX looking for yours packages
                           % (not in main tree)
                           % here you can collect all styles, which 
                           % you use in yours TikZ pictures
% small picture bell
        bell/.pic = {%path [use as bounding box] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2); do really need them?
\draw [in= 90,out=180]  (0,0.75) coordinate (-top)  to 
                        (-0.5,0) coordinate (-bottom left);
\draw [in= 90,out=  0]  (0,0.75) to 
                        (0.5, 0) coordinate (-bottom right);
\draw [in=270,out=-90, looseness=0.75] (-0.5,0) to (+0.5,0);
                    }%
                        },% end of bell style
% for nodes with rectangular shape
       box/.style = {draw, line width=1mm, inner sep=1mm,
                     minimum width = 44mm, minimum height=33mm,
                     font=\itshape, align=left},
% for shortening lines on the both sides                    
shorten <>/.style = {shorten < = #1, shorten > = #1},
% etc 
             }% end of tikzset
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
% \endinput

\usepackage[graphics,tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[PIC]
% demo for connecting small pictures width line
\pic[red]   at (0,0) (A)    {bell};
\pic[blue]  at (3,0) (B)    {bell};
\draw[dotted, ultra thick,shorten <>=2mm]  (A-bottom right) -- (B-bottom left);
% demo for use it as stamp on letter envelope
\node[box,below right] (C) at (-0.75,-0.5) {To my\\ dearest\\ Clementine};
\pic[below left=of C.north east] (D) {bell};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

In design of above MWE I only partly follows yours. I allow to myseld some freedom in picture design :-). In MWE is  considered only definitions and packages, which are relevant for it. This MWE gives:

[image]

Comment: @asdf, see my answer. Let me know, if this approach can solve your problems?

Answer (score 2):

This is not dissimilar to [Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282830/). I also use a `pic` and, following Zarko, I've called it `bell`.

What I would do is create a small TikZ library which you can load along with other libraries when you wish to use caps of this kind in your pictures.

I am not entirely sure what the purpose of the different layers is, so I've elaborated it in a particular way in the hope that you will be able to see how to modify the code for your own needs.

First, the library code. I suggest saving this as `tikzlibrarybell.code.tex` under `<TEXMFHOME>/tex/generic/pgf/`. `<TEXMFHOME>` is your personal `texmf` tree. In TeX Live, `kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME` will give you the path. However, if you only want it for one picture, you can save it in your working directory instead. The particular file name allows TikZ to find it when you say `\usetikzlibrary{bell}`.

If I understood the key-value stuff better, this code would doubtless be improved significantly. This is the product of my current efforts and my current understanding.

Note that the use of `/bell` here prevents possible conflicts with standard keys or keys from other libraries. For example, I am using `/bell/cap` rather than plain `cap` so nothing here will hamper the use of `cap` line endings. The use of `cap` in this code is strictly local to the `/bell` key path.

```
% tikzlibrarybell.code.tex
\ProvidesFile{tikzlibrarybell.code.tex}
\pgfdeclarelayer{bell edge layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{bell node layer}
\pgfsetlayers{bell edge layer,bell node layer,main}
\tikzset{% modified from code at tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarybackgrounds.code.tex
  on bell edge layer/.style={%
    execute at begin scope={%
      \pgfonlayer{bell edge layer}%
      \let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty%
      \tikzset{every on bell edge layer/.try,#1}%
      \tikz@options%
    },
    execute at end scope={\endpgfonlayer}
  },
  on bell node layer/.style={%
    execute at begin scope={%
      \pgfonlayer{bell node layer}%
      \let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty%
      \tikzset{every on bell node layer/.try,#1}%
      \tikz@options%
    },
    execute at end scope={\endpgfonlayer}
  },
  pics/bell/.style={%
    code={%
      \tikzset{%
        /bell/.cd,
        #1,
        /tikz/.cd,
      }%
      \path [use as bounding box] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
      \begin{scope}[on bell node layer]
        \node [pic actions, /bell/node style] (a) at (0, 0.75) {\bell@top@node};
        \node [pic actions, /bell/node style] (b) at (-0.5, 0) {\bell@left@node};
        \node [pic actions, /bell/node style] (c) at (0.5, 0) {\bell@right@node};
      \end{scope}
      \begin{scope}[on bell edge layer]
        \path [pic actions, /bell/cap style] (c.center) [in=0, out=90] to (a.center) [in=90, out=180] to (b.center) [in=270, out=-90, looseness=0.75]  to (c.center);
      \end{scope}
    }%
  },
  /bell/.search also={/tikz},
  /bell/.cd,
  top/.store in=\bell@top@node,
  left/.store in=\bell@left@node,
  right/.store in=\bell@right@node,
  % this cannot be the right way to do this!!!
  cap/.code={\tikzset{/bell/cap style/.style={/tikz/.cd, #1}}},
  nodes/.code={\tikzset{/bell/node style/.style={/tikz/.cd, #1}}},
  top=,
  left=,
  right=,
  cap style/.style={draw},
  node style/.style=,
}
\endinput
```

This defines a `pic` called `bell` which takes one optional argument. If specified, the argument should be options for the bell. In addition to standard TikZ options, you can use

- `cap={<style for cap itself>}`
- `nodes={<style for nodes, if any>}`
- `top={<text for node at top>}`
- `left={<text for node at bottom left>}`
- `right={<text for node at bottom right>}`

By default, the shape is simply drawn and the nodes are all empty with no styling.

Given this library, we can create a row of `bell` `pic`s in the following way:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,bell}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic {bell};
  \pic at (2,0) {bell={%
      nodes={fill opacity=.75, text=blue, text opacity=1, inner color=blue!10, outer color=blue!30, font=\sffamily, inner sep=0pt, shape=ellipse},
      cap={draw=blue!50!black, ball color=blue!50, thick},
      top={top},
      left={left},
      right={right},
    }};
  \pic at (4,0) {bell={%
      nodes={text=red, draw=red, thick, fill=white, font=\sffamily, inner sep=1pt, shape=circle},
      cap={draw=red, thick, inner color=red!95!black, outer color=red!75!black},
      top={A},
      left={B},
      right={C},
    }};
  \pic at (6,0) {bell};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: bells]

The `pic actions` in the code means that you can also pass additional options which should affect all elements of the `pic`. However, this should not conflict with the options in use for `lines` and `nodes` or you may end up with weird results. (For example, try `\pic [fill=green!10] {bell};` to see what I mean!)

Here's an example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic [rotate=90] {bell};
  \pic at (2,0) [rotate=-90] {bell={nodes={draw, circle, fill=white, inner sep=1pt, font=\sffamily}, top=1, left=2, right=3, cap={draw, fill=gray!25}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: rotated bells]

Complete code:

```
\begin{filecontents}{tikzlibrarybell.code.tex}
% tikzlibrarybell.code.tex
\ProvidesFile{tikzlibrarybell.code.tex}
\pgfdeclarelayer{bell edge layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{bell node layer}
\pgfsetlayers{bell edge layer,bell node layer,main}
\tikzset{% modified from code at tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarybackgrounds.code.tex
  on bell edge layer/.style={%
    execute at begin scope={%
      \pgfonlayer{bell edge layer}%
      \let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty%
      \tikzset{every on bell edge layer/.try,#1}%
      \tikz@options%
    },
    execute at end scope={\endpgfonlayer}
  },
  on bell node layer/.style={%
    execute at begin scope={%
      \pgfonlayer{bell node layer}%
      \let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty%
      \tikzset{every on bell node layer/.try,#1}%
      \tikz@options%
    },
    execute at end scope={\endpgfonlayer}
  },
  pics/bell/.style={%
    code={%
      \tikzset{%
        /bell/.cd,
        #1,
        /tikz/.cd,
      }%
      \path [use as bounding box] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
      \begin{scope}[on bell node layer]
        \node [pic actions, /bell/node style] (a) at (0, 0.75) {\bell@top@node};
        \node [pic actions, /bell/node style] (b) at (-0.5, 0) {\bell@left@node};
        \node [pic actions, /bell/node style] (c) at (0.5, 0) {\bell@right@node};
      \end{scope}
      \begin{scope}[on bell edge layer]
        \path [pic actions, /bell/cap style] (c.center) [in=0, out=90] to (a.center) [in=90, out=180] to (b.center) [in=270, out=-90, looseness=0.75]  to (c.center);
      \end{scope}
    }%
  },
  /bell/.search also={/tikz},
  /bell/.cd,
  top/.store in=\bell@top@node,
  left/.store in=\bell@left@node,
  right/.store in=\bell@right@node,
  % this cannot be the right way to do this!!!
  cap/.code={\tikzset{/bell/cap style/.style={/tikz/.cd, #1}}},
  nodes/.code={\tikzset{/bell/node style/.style={/tikz/.cd, #1}}},
  top=,
  left=,
  right=,
  cap style/.style={draw},
  node style/.style=,
}
\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,bell}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic {bell};
  \pic at (2,0) {bell={%
      nodes={fill opacity=.75, text=blue, text opacity=1, inner color=blue!10, outer color=blue!30, font=\sffamily, inner sep=0pt, shape=ellipse},
      cap={draw=blue!50!black, ball color=blue!50, thick},
      top={top},
      left={left},
      right={right},
    }};
  \pic at (4,0) {bell={%
      nodes={text=red, draw=red, thick, fill=white, font=\sffamily, inner sep=1pt, shape=circle},
      cap={draw=red, thick, inner color=red!95!black, outer color=red!75!black},
      top={A},
      left={B},
      right={C},
    }};
  \pic at (6,0) {bell};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic [rotate=90] {bell};
  \pic at (2,0) [rotate=-90] {bell={nodes={draw, circle, fill=white, inner sep=1pt, font=\sffamily}, top=1, left=2, right=3, cap={draw, fill=gray!25}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice solution. From it I learned a lot. Since  I use MikTeX,  I'm not familiar with `<TEXMFHOME>`. Is this main directory for (La)TeX or it is local directory as is `localtexmf` at MikTeX?  I suppose, that "private  libraries" should be stored locally.

Comment: And one remark: as I mentioned, using `cap` for some own style can make problems since it is used as option in `arrows.meta` library. That is reason, why I "invented name "bell" for use instead it.

Comment: @Zarko I agree. But I'm not using `/tikz/cap` or `/pgf/cap` or anything else which would conflict with the use of the `cap` line ending, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I've tried to clarify this and explained `TEXMFHOME`.

Comment: Thank you! I assume this, however I wasn't sure.